# How to get values from views in a recyclerview after they are scrolled out of screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a fragment that contains a RecyclerView. This RecyclerView will contain several different types of views (EditText, Seekbar, CheckBox, etc..) and it will work as a sort of Form. I have also a button the performs a save, that should go to each row of the RecyclerView and get the value the user inputs.

I also have an Adapter that inflates different layouts depending on the type of view I want to add on the RecyclerView.
In this adapter, i have a "getValuesFromViews" method that reads the user input depending on the view type.

```
public String getValuesFromViews(int position,ViewHolder vHolder){
 //...
}
```

In my fragment, during a For loop, I call this method, after getting a ViewHolder with findViewHolderForAdapterPosition

My problem is that when I scroll my RecyclerView, I lose the ViewHolders for the positions not shown on screen and so the findViewHolderForAdapterPosition returns null.

How can I read values from views not shown on screen?

**EDIT**
here is my adapter at the moment (still working on it).

```
public class ParamsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ParamsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private final Fragment fragment;
    private Context context;
    private View view1;


    ParamsAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder1;
    List<UserConfigurableParametersResponseMainItem1> listParams;

    public ParamsAdapter(Context context1, List<UserConfigurableParametersResponseMainItem1> list, android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fmanager, Fragment frag){
        context = context1;
        listParams = list;
        fragmentManager = fmanager;
        fragment = frag;
    }

    public List<UserConfigurableParametersResponseMainItem1> getListParams() {
        return listParams;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        @BindView(R.id.tv_param_title)
        TextViewMPOS tvParamTitle;
        @BindView(R.id.iv_question)
        ImageView ivQuestion;
        @Nullable @BindView(R.id.et_param)
        View param;
        @BindView(R.id.param_loader)
        AVLoadingIndicatorView loader;
        @BindView(R.id.iv_status)
        ImageView iv_status;
        @BindView(R.id.iv_error)
        ImageView iv_error;
        @BindView(R.id.tv_param_error)
        TextViewMPOS tvError;
        @BindView(R.id.iv_reset)
        ImageView ivReset;

        public ViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            ButterKnife.bind(this,v);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public ParamsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){

        view1 = createViews(parent,viewType);
        viewHolder1 = new ParamsAdapter.ViewHolder(view1);

        return viewHolder1;
    }

    private View createViews(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ConfigurableParameterWebControlCode op = listParams.get(viewType).getParamWbCntrlCd();
        switch (op){
            case NUMERO:
                return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_param_num,parent,false);
            case DOUBLE:
                return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_param_double,parent,false);
            case EMAIL:
                return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_param_email,parent,false);
            case TEXTBOX:
                return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_param_text,parent,false);
            case TEXAREA:
                return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_param_textarea,parent,false);
            case SLIDER:
                return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_param_slider,parent,false);
            case CHECKBOX:
                return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_param_num,parent,false);
            case DROPDOWN:
                return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_param_drop,parent,false);
            case RADIOBUTTON:
                return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_param_num,parent,false);
            case DATA:
                return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_param_data,parent,false);
            case DATAHORA:
                return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_param_datahora,parent,false);
            case TEMPO:
                return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_param_tempo,parent,false);
/*            case PHONE:
                return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_param_phone,parent,false);*/
            case CHECKGROUP:
                return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_param_checkgroup,parent,false);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ParamsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position){

        final int index = getLanguageIndex(position);
        holder.tvParamTitle.setText(listParams.get(position).getUsrCnfgrblPrmtrsRspnItms().get(index).getLablTxt());
        holder.ivQuestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(context != null)
                    MyDialogBuilder.createSingleButtonDialog(context,R.drawable.ic_warningcor,listParams.get(position).getUsrCnfgrblPrmtrsRspnItms().get(index).getHlprTxt(),R.string.ok,null,-1).show();
            }
        });
        holder.ivReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clearView(holder,position);
            }
        });

        holder.iv_error.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(context != null)
                    MyDialogBuilder.createSingleButtonDialog(context,R.drawable.ic_errorcor,listParams.get(position).getUsrCnfgrblPrmtrsRspnItms().get(index).getErrTxt(),R.string.ok,null,-1).show();
            }
        });


        switch (listParams.get(position).getParamWbCntrlCd()){

            case NUMERO:
            case DOUBLE:
            case EMAIL:
            case TEXTBOX:
            case TEXAREA:
            case TELEFONE:
                EditTextMPOS editTextAux = (EditTextMPOS)holder.param;
                if (editTextAux != null) {
                    editTextAux.setText(listParams.get(position).getParamVl());
                }
                break;
            case SLIDER:
                AppCompatSeekBar seekbarAux = (AppCompatSeekBar)holder.param;
                seekbarAux.setMax(Integer.parseInt(listParams.get(position).getParamVldtnMax()));
                seekbarAux.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                        holder.tvParamTitle.setText(listParams.get(position).getUsrCnfgrblPrmtrsRspnItms().get(index).getLablTxt() +"   "+i);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }
                });
                break;
            case CHECKBOX:
                break;
            case DROPDOWN:
                break;
            case RADIOBUTTON:
                break;

            case DATA:
                if (holder.param != null) {
                    holder.param.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            MyDialogBuilder.DialogDateNoHoursPicker(context,fragmentManager,fragment, DatePickerFragment.DATE_END,"# ",0);
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case DATAHORA:
                if (holder.param != null) {
                    holder.param.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            MyDialogBuilder.DialogDatePicker(context,fragmentManager,fragment, DatePickerFragment.DATE_END,"##",0);
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case TEMPO:
                if (holder.param != null) {
                    holder.param.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            MyDialogBuilder.DialogTimePicker(context,fragmentManager,fragment, DatePickerFragment.DATE_END,"###",0);
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case CHECKGROUP:
                LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)holder.param;
                List<String> checkList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(listParams.get(position).getParamVldtnRgExp().split(";")));
                for(int i=0;i<checkList.size();i++){
                    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(context);
                    checkBox.setText(checkList.get(i));
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        newParams.weight = 1;
                        checkBox.setLayoutParams(newParams);

                    linearLayout.addView(checkBox,i);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void clearView(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (listParams.get(position).getParamWbCntrlCd()){
            case NUMERO:
            case DOUBLE:
            case EMAIL:
            case TEXTBOX:
            case TEXAREA:
            case TELEFONE:
                EditTextMPOS auxView = (EditTextMPOS)holder.param;
                if (auxView != null) {
                    auxView.setText("");
                    auxView.setHint(listParams.get(position).getDfltVl());
                }
                listParams.get(position).setUseDefault(true);
                break;
            case CHECKBOX:
                break;
            case DROPDOWN:
                break;
            case RADIOBUTTON:
                break;
            case DATA:
                if (holder.param != null) {
                    holder.param.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            MyDialogBuilder.DialogDateNoHoursPicker(context,fragmentManager,fragment, DatePickerFragment.DATE_END,"# ",0);
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case DATAHORA:
                if (holder.param != null) {
                    holder.param.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            MyDialogBuilder.DialogDatePicker(context,fragmentManager,fragment, DatePickerFragment.DATE_END,"##",0);
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case TEMPO:
                if (holder.param != null) {
                    holder.param.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            MyDialogBuilder.DialogTimePicker(context,fragmentManager,fragment, DatePickerFragment.DATE_END,"###",0);
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case CHECKGROUP:
                break;
        }
    }

    private int getLanguageIndex(int position) {
        int index = 0;
        String lang = HelperSharedPreferences.getSharedPreferencesString(context,HelperSharedPreferences.LANG,"pt-PT");
        for (int i=0; i<listParams.get(position).getUsrCnfgrblPrmtrsRspnItms().size();i++) {
            if(listParams.get(position).getUsrCnfgrblPrmtrsRspnItms().get(i).getLangCd().equals(lang)) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    public String getValuesFromViews(int position,ViewHolder vHolder){
        String result = new String();
        if(listParams.get(position).isUseDefault()) {
            result = null;
        }
        else {
            switch (listParams.get(position).getParamWbCntrlCd()) {
                case NUMERO:
                case DOUBLE:
                case EMAIL:
                case TEXTBOX:
                case TEXAREA:
                case TELEFONE:
                    EditTextMPOS auxView = (EditTextMPOS) vHolder.param;
                    if (auxView != null) {
                        result = auxView.getText().toString();
                    }
                    break;
                case CHECKBOX:

                    break;
                case CHECKGROUP:
                    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)vHolder.param;
                    for(int i = 0;i<linearLayout.getChildCount();i++){
                        if(((CheckBox)linearLayout.getChildAt(i)).isChecked()){
                            result += ((CheckBox)linearLayout.getChildAt(i)).getText() + ";";
                        }
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }
        Logging.log("RESULT ",result);
        return result;
    }


    public void setStatus(final int position, ViewHolder vHolder,int status){
        if (status == 1) {
            vHolder.iv_status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vHolder.iv_error.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            vHolder.param.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text_background);
        } else if (status == 2) {
            vHolder.iv_status.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            vHolder.iv_error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vHolder.param.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text_error_background);
        } else {
            vHolder.iv_status.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            vHolder.iv_error.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (vHolder.param != null) {
                vHolder.param.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text_background);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        if(listParams != null)
            return listParams.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public void update (List<UserConfigurableParametersResponseMainItem1> list){
        this.listParams.clear();
        this.listParams = list;
        setDataChanged();
    }

    public void setDataChanged(){
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and the Data im getting to create it is an array of things like this

```
    {

    "ParamCd":"xxxxxxx",
    "ParamVl":"xxxxxxx",
    "DfltVl":" ",
    "ParamVldtnRgExp":".*",
    "ParamWbCntrlCd":"EMAIL",   
    "ParamOrdr":54,
    "UsrCnfgrblPrmtrsRspnItms":[
        {
            "LangCd":"pt-PT",
            "LablTxt":"xxxxxxx",
            "HlprTxt":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "ErrTxt":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "LangCd":"en-UK",
            "LablTxt":"xxxxxxx",
            "HlprTxt":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "ErrTxt":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

The field "ParamWbCntrlCd" is what defines the sort of view that appears in the RecyclerView Row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android, adapters are used to create views representing a specific dataset. You can see adapters as a kind of bridge between *data* and *display*.

Therefore, ViewHolder are representations of your data at a given position. As views generally takes more memory than pure data, `RecyclerView` reuses them while scrolling. That's why you can't retrieve data associated with views that scrolled out of the screen: those ViewHolder have been recycled, and the previous state of their views has been lost.

To solve this problem, I suggests you the following steps:

1. Create a `SparseArray<UserConfigurableParametersResponseMainItem1>` as a field of your Adapter. This [SparseArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) will contain copies of your model object that have been modified by the user.
2. Configure listeners for each View in your ViewHolders whose content could be modified.

For each interesting change, call `holder.getAdapterPosition()` to retrieve the current position of this ViewHolder in the dataset. Use that `position` to check if an object exists at this position in the `SparseArray`. If it does not exist, create a copy of the original data at the same position from `listParams`. Then set the properties of this object to reflect the changes the user made.

The idea is to maintain a "cache" of modifications made by user in the adapter. This way, modifications made by user are no longer lost.

3. In `onBindViewHolder`, retrieve the data from the given `position` in the SparseArray. If it is `null`, then no modifications have been issued, and you can bind data from `listParams`. Otherwise, modifications have been made by user, and you have to bind those instead of your original.
4. Create a method `UserConfigurableParametersResponseMainItem1 getModificationsForPosition(int position)`. This method directly maps to data contained in the `SparseArray`. This way, the calling `Fragment` is directly aware that a modification occur if the returned value is not `null`.
5. When clicking on the "Save" button, use a for-loop to call `getModificationsForPosition(i)` for every valid position of your adapter, retrieving all modified objects, then save them wherever you want (SQLite or remote server).
6. Refresh your adapter's dataset based on saved changes. For example, you may replace data in `listParams` with the ones from the sparse array. Don't forget to clear the sparse array when the "Save" button has been clicked.

This construct has the following advantages:

- Modifications to views are kept even after ViewHolders have been recycled.
- Modifications can be discarded individually for each position.
- You only save data that have been modified, which is more efficient.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks for the help